# Removing/Deinitializing a Facebook pixel in multi-pixel scenario

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-marketing-api

When using multiple pixels on a site, is there any way to remove a previously initialized pixel id (using fbq('init')) to avoid sending future tracking events to this id?

Comment: did you find a solution to this? thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid not. This functionality is still missing/undocumented on fb.

Comment: I'm sooo looking for this. Does anybody know more about it after 2 years?

Comment: @TimKohlen no change in 2 years unfortunately.